# User id detected as phone number on Mobile Safari

Tags: bug, design, mobile-web

When I select a tag on the "Activity" tab of a user in the Mobile Safari
on an iPhone, the user id is "auto-detected" as a phone number,
and clicking on the user id initiates a phone call:

[image]

I could observe that behaviour only on Stack Overflow, not on other
Stack Exchange sites, and I am fairly sure that this is a recent change.

Comment: That will be a setting somewhere in your browser or phone. Nothing to do with [so]. See [How to disable phone number linking in Mobile Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/226131)

Comment: @DavidPostill: Well, it *can* be disabled in the HTML code provided by the server (as your link shows), and I think it should. I could disable it on the phone only globally. – Also I am pretty sure that that did not happen some days ago, and it does not happen on other SE sites.

Comment: You are in Germany - I *think* Safari's phone-number auto-detection should take that into account and not detect a number like that, which wouldn't be a valid number in the country? I'm not completely sure. Maybe it's a bug on Safari's end? Or you accidentally changed your country setting to a country where that *is* a valid phone number? That seems unlikely though.

Comment: @Pekka 웃 user 110 proved to be extremely motivated, they even suggested visiting me at home. Among other things, they are experts on illegal behaviour. So if your code is against the specification, they should quickly spot that. Yes, it's "them", because there's always another person on the phone. I suppose this is to be active on SO 24/7. I'd say all members of the team should get a badge, but they all have one already on their blue shirts. Most of them are probably mods because they carry handcuffs and guns.

Comment: @null yes, the support team at 110 is *extremely* proactive. Proof that not all customer service in Europe is crappy

Comment: This also happens with the view counts on some questions. E.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object-in-javascript

Comment: From [Apple URL Scheme Reference | Phone Links](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html): *"In Safari on iOS, telephone number detection is on by default. However, if your webpage contains numbers that can be interpreted as phone numbers, but are not phone numbers, you can turn off telephone number detection [by setting] the `format-detection` meta tag as follows: `<meta name = "format-detection" content = "telephone=no">`"*.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243640/215176

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this happens because 7-digit numbers (such as most user IDs on Stack Overflow) are valid phone numbers in some countries.

In other words, you probably stumbled upon something that is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

Comment: Good point about the 7-digit numbers. However, I am fairly sure that this did not happen some time ago, so something must have changed.

Comment: @MartinR: no, it has been like that for ages on my iPad as well. It is possible to add some HTML attributes to suppress it - but it is *superbly* annoying. And why should all webpage authors in the world bow to Apple anyway  It's *them* who ought to disable it entirely, or at least make it a user preference.

Comment: It would make more sense for web pages to be able to opt *in* to treating a number as a phone number, rather than having to add attributes to opt *out*.

Comment: I think its a bug; and I don't believe [tag:status-bydesign] would be a good choice to dismiss it. When Safari browsers are detected, `<meta name = "format-detection" content = "telephone=no">` can be used to disable the documented behavior. Also see [Apple URL Scheme Reference | Phone Links](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html).